# How to handle the MFA authentication in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am testing an application which is configured with Microsoft AD MFA. Whenever i login into application with my user id and pwd, i receive a push notification in my mobile from microsoft authenticator application which states "Approve" or "Deny" request.

Here we need to find out solutions for these two below mentioned problems :-

1. how can we handle the push notification that we receive in mobile while login using JMeter[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4aji.jpg).
2. how to perform the load test execution with these 2MFA enabled by handling the push notification and token expiry.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Your test should focus **on your application only** any external dependencies must be excluded. You are not load testing Microsoft servers, are you?

So if your test is making requests to one of the ["forbidden websites"](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733009-Websites-Forbidden-to-Test-Using-BlazeMeter) most probably these requests need to be removed.

- If for some reason it's not possible - ask around if it's possible to turn off Azure authentication.
- If it's not possible - ask whether it's possible to turn off the 2nd factor.
- If it's not possible - ask whether it's possible to [switch it to something](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks) you can handle easily like `OATH Software token`
- As the last resort you can use a browser automation framework like [Appium](http://appium.io/) for automating the approval process on your mobile device/simulator

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, that's help me with some understanding on this problem.